# Custom shape node in swift

Tags: swift, sprite, shapes

Is there any way to create a custom shape node in swift and make it interact properly with other shapes (using SpriteKit)?
I tried to do some stuff but all I coud do is circle and square/rectangle. I'm interested in something a little more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build more difficult shapes, you have to work with [CGPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/index.html).

It's a bit complicated to do it by yourself, but there are great editors which support creating shapes and which also create the cgpath for you. [Example](http://adriancooney.ie/SKImport/Editor/)